# Do helicopter rotor blades speed up and down during the rotation?

Tags: helicopter

Does the inertia force change the angular velocity due to increase-decrease in the radius when the blade travels up? Does this cause an excessive bending moment?

Comment: This is what I understand that the question is, please feel free to roll back or edit otherwise if I did not get it right.

Answer (score 2):

A helicopter rotor usually has flapping hinges, which lifts the blade up when travelling forward and down when travelling backwards. The blade being at an angle indeed causes a change in effective moment of inertia: it would want to speed up when at an incline, and this would indeed cause a bending or warping moment were it not for..

[image]

..the Drag Hinge or lead/lag hinge. The image is from [this site](http://www.danubewings.com/fully-articulated-rotor-system/) which contains an explanation on other rotor heads as well.